# How to populate the unit # based on the last max number in a range in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried creating a table to aid a manufacturing process. Where technicians perform some test and record the results. One of the column (unit #) auto populates based on other column entries of the table.

The unit # column helps keep track since a technician is supposed to test 14 units in a shift (4 different shifts - 1,2,3,4). The way I wrote the formula, it populates an "out of range" message when the unit being tested is not conforming to the standards and the tech needs to move on to the next unit. Leaving the "out of range" entry as is (this entry is needed for record keeping).

The table works as intended unless there are consecutive "out of range" units in the column. Then it goes back to unit# 1 (instead of unit#8 in case of this example)

[What table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9m9A.png)

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C16="","",IF(OR(AG16="Too Thick",AG16="Too Thin"),"Out of Range",IF(OR([@DATE]<>D15,C16<>C15),1,IF(OR(AG15="Too Thick",AG15="Too Thin"),IF([@DATE]=D14,AE14+1,1),AE15+1)))),"1")
```

What changes would you suggest I make to my formula? I tried MAXIFS at the end but got a !spill# error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I just had to add another if statement at the end.

```
,IF(OR(AG14={"Too thick","Too Thin"}),"Out of range",MAXIFS(AE$13:AE13,C$14:C14,C14,D$14:D14,D14)+1)
```